# Grid must be flexible on all viewports

Tags: html, css

I have created a page here: http://goo.gl/r7REXn and its a grid that contains a basic three column layout. The issue here as you narrow down the size of the screen from 998px the layout doesn't look good and it doesn't go over on the whole spaces of screen. It must be smooth on all of the viewports.

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb1.png">
  <h4>Video #1 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb2.png" width="300">
  <h4>Video #2 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb3.png">
  <h4>Video #3 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb4.png">
  <h4>Video #4 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb5.png">
  <h4>Video #5 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb6.png">
  <h4>Video #6- Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-1-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
margin: 1%;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-block{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can I make sure it is smooth layout and looks good on all browser any fix?

Comment: You should use media query for that. to make it good visible for all size of screen

Comment: can you show it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Using media queries is the way to go to make full responsive webs.

With your code you could just add:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-1-3 {width: 44%;}  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .col-1-3 {width: 94%;}
}
```

This css changes or modified or overwritte whatever css propertie you need to reach your desired behaviour. I have just used 767 and 590 window width as an example but you can use whatever break points you need.

```css
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-1-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
margin: 1%;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-block{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-1-3 {width: 44%;}
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .col-1-3 {width: 94%;}
  
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb1.png">
  <h4>Video #1 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb2.png" width="300">
  <h4>Video #2 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb3.png">
  <h4>Video #3 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb4.png">
  <h4>Video #4 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb5.png">
  <h4>Video #5 - Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb6.png">
  <h4>Video #6- Know Yourself</h4>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/2o0fmu82/)**

**Edited:**

However, when using floating responsive layouts, I would recomend you to use “perfect” widths as 20%, 25%, 33.3333%, 50%, etc to make sure your content always fill the container, and if you want to use margins between elements there are many css solutions avalaible to cancel the margin to elements that woudl break the layout (like last element of every row if using margin-right). As an example is worth more tan words (specially when english not my main lenguaje) you can check this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/9s916tcw/)**

Answer (score 0):

i debugged your code and found out that you have some trouble with your media query and padding, refer images.

in this you have `padding-right:245px`

[image]

i removed the `padding-right` and it was center align like before.
[image]